# Access existing API gateway by ARN

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I'm building a **Step Function** using **CDK**. I need to call call external service using **WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN** integration pattern. This external service is a separate CDK stack.

Previously, this was done using **SQS** queue:

```
new SqsSendMessage(stack, "Name", {
  queue: Queue.fromQueueArn("existing queue arn"),
  integrationPattern: IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
  ...
})
```

I used the ARN of the existing queue in order to define the queue for the integration.

Now I'd like to replace this with a call to the API defined in that other CDK stack. With the queue I could easily access existing one by providing its ARN, which seems not to be possible with API Gateway. **CallApiGatewayRestApiEndpoint** requires that I pass existing a CDK object of type **IRestApi**, but I don't see a way to get this object from its ARN.

Am I missing something or is it only possible to **CallApiGatewayRestApiEndpoint** to APIs defined in the same CDK stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a read-only `IRestApi` reference to an existing API Gateway with the [fromRestApiId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html#static-fromwbrrestwbrapiwbridscope-id-restapiid) static method:

```js
const api: IRestApi = RestApi.fromRestApiId(this, 'ApiRef', 'my-api-id');
```

Note that this [interface-type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces) construct is a glorified wrapper for the ApiId.  The CDK accepts your ApiId without question, performing no cloud-side lookups or validation.

It's not much, but it's exactly what `CallApiGatewayRestApiEndpoint` needs. `CallApiGatewayRestApiEndpoint` is the CDK implementation of the Step Function API Gateway [Optimized Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html).  The integration [expects an endpoint URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html#connect-api-gateway-requests), not an ARN.  The `api: IRestApi` prop is used to assemble that URL, which has the form `<API ID>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com`.